# Compiling OpenCV SVN trunk in Windows - error in highgui/libVideoInput

Tags: qt, opencv, makefile, compiler-errors, cmake

I know there are several questions about this but none has shown me what I can do against the error I get.

Using [this guide](http://knowtheabc.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/windows-opencv-and-qt-creator/) I already was able to compile the current OpenCV Release (2.2) using this guide and cmake. So the release works fine and I can write code using it in Qt. Therefore I need WITH_QT enabled and need to build myself.

But unfortunately I found out that the 2.2 release doesn't support all types of cameras (since I would like to get the camera stream from a 720p webcam). I've read that this is fixed in the latest svn trunk version.

So I checked the newest svn trunk out and ran Cmake again, created a new folder, selected the source files, MinGW compile with links to the g++.exe and qcc.exe, configured and enabled "WITH_QT" and generated the necessary Makefiles.

I then started a Windows Powershell as Admin and tried to compile with "mingw32-make"... but at 56% it suddenly crashes with this:

```
[ 56%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_sunras.obj
[ 56%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_tiff.obj
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_highgui220d.dll
Creating library file: ..\..\lib\libopencv_highgui220d.dll.a
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
ee): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
104): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
2a6): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
2d4): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
2fe): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
314): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
4b6): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
4e4): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
1b41): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
1b5a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
1bb4): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
1c03): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
1c88): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
1ca7): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
2265): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
228d): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
2318): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
2337): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
28f5): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
291d): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
38a0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
38df): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
406b): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
40a3): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
4211): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
42ec): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
6cf8): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
6d17): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
6e1e): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
6e3e): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
7002): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
70b4): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
70cd): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
7111): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
742e): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:\workspace\opencv\OpenCV_SVN\modules\highgui\..\..\3rdparty\lib/libvideoInput.a(videoInput.o):videoInput.cpp:(.text+0x
7501): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_highgui220d.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So it seems to have something going wrong when compiling the libVideoInput...
is anybody familiar with this error? How can I fix it? Do I need to install anything special before?

Would be great if anybody could help me! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested here? http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Error-compiling-OpenCV-with-MinGW-and-Qt-td5445502.html

Comment: Thanks for the link... I just tried that... copied the libvideoinput.a from the 2.2 release source into the downloaded svn trunk and compiled, but with same error... I even tried the one from the 2.1 release... no change though...

Comment: I also just tried to compile the 2.1 release but I get the same error as with the 2.2 SVN trunk... 2.2 release works though...

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, by installing OpenCV with QT, you do not need highgui library. So during the installation of OpenCV, you should deselect highgui from Cmake gui. There are some tutorials on Youtube/Web that are showed how to use OpenCV and QT without highgui lib. Good luck with that

Comment: I think a better solution is to select highgui and deselect the option "WITH_QT "  in Cmake gui, since you may need to read and write an image.